# How to defeat Molag Bal?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I have found the Molag Bal boss fight impossible. I'm fighting with a VR1 Sorcerer and all combinations of food/potions/skillsets have been to no avail.

Is there something I'm missing that would greatly help defeating him and his army of ridiculous dragons? Should I wait until VR10 to do this? Have you guys been able to beat him at VR1?

I have, of course, gotten the "divine blessing" uber-duber buff beforehand. Please advise.

Comment: I know some ppl are having luck with throwing a couple points in Bow and kiting him to death.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of initial failures and experiments for the right skillset I finally managed to win. Here's what I used:

Destruction staff

- Velocious curse (instant cast for good damage)
- Endless fury (excellent for finishing him off under 20%)
- Conjured ward (damage shield)
- Bolt escape (imperative for **kiting** him)
- Entropy (excellent DoT with HoT)

Healing staff

- Blessing of restoration (good for emergency instant heal)
- Dark deal (replenishes health and mana at cost of stamina, as well as a good defense buff)
- Bolt escape
- Rapid regeneration (excellent HoT, kept it consistently running)
- Healing springs (good main heal)

**Notes**

> Avoid using any spell/attack that slows down your movement. You don't
> want to get caught close to him. Heavy staff attacks and crystal
> shards, I found, were complete no-no's. I didn't have to use any of my
> ultimates, but Negate Magic (or any ability that silences enemies)
> would have surely helped.
>
> When the dragons come and attack in a large group, **be sure to *block*
> with your weapon**. The "god mode" buff allows you to deflect their
> ranged attacks back at them. Just walk around deflecting and healing
> while the dragons are present.
>
> I did this with stage 4 vampirism, i.e., SUPER SLOW health
> regeneration. Still pulled it off with the good HoT spells.
>
> If you use summoned creatures, note that they won't agro Molag Bal at all. He only attacks you.
>
> Most people I talked to were able to beat him at VR1, so it's
> not uncommon to do so.

[This guy's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCqUkU2BvIE) shows another VR1 Sorcerer beating Molag Bal. He used a similar skillset to beat him and it's written in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I killed him in 1 attempt, was surprised of how easy it was, was level 47 or so with one handed and shield, fought him alone and he was dead in under 5 mins or so :).
It was very close though

I recommend using rune focus if you are templar otherwise abilities to increase you armor and magic resistance, some good health restoring potions and 1 healing ability.

You should be fine as long as you dont let him cast to many spells, if you see him casting go interrupt him.

Answer (score -1):

I finally beat him today with my dw templar.  The trick is stay away from him and hit with javelin and bolts...With a few up close hit and run. When the adds spawn just stand and block. Throw in some basic hits. I had no real self heals other then 6 good health pots. Some food to boost stamina and magica. It is a long battle but it works...If you have a bow to switch to every so often use that as well. It was basically...run, turn towards him...few hits...run again...stay out of red zones...run...hit...run again. Hopefully that helps some.